# Objects created by Blender see through on Unity

Tags: unity

I created simple rooms with planes and cubes by Blender 2.83 and exported it as fbx file.

[image]

Then I imported it into Unity, and its inner walls are transparent.

[image]

Why? Will anybody help me resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Backface culling. Don't know if possible to avoid it in Unity. But if not, solidify the model in Blender.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reaction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this effect is that in game engines like Unity, typically only one side of every face is rendered. Faces have a front and a back, and only the front of a face is rendered. This is typically done because in many circumstances, the back sides of faces are never seen, and it is much more efficient to never render them.

To better preview what your mesh is going to look like in Unity, you can turn on Backface Culling in Blender.

[image]

If you do need a face to be visible from both sides in Unity, you can duplicate that face in Blender, and flip the normals (the direction the face is pointing) by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, then <kbd>F</kbd>.

Typically though, real life objects (like walls) aren't infinitely thin, so you will usually have a face defining either side of a wall, with some distance in between.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I will try that!